# Polynomial with positive integer coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Prove that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients such that $P(n)$ is a perfect square for every integer $n$, the degree of $P(x)$ must be even.

Comment: Tried using Diophantine equation  but couldnot proceed

Comment: If it has odd degree, then it takes negative values.

Comment: instead of pulling apart a perfect-square polynomial, try to consider how it may have been built.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any of the machinery of the analysis of Diophantine equations.

**Hint** What is the behavior of an odd polynomial $P(x)$ as $x \to \pm \infty$?

Comment: It is negative both ways

Comment: When x is positive it is opposite and  reverses when x is negative

Comment: for even degree it is positive both ways

Comment: Square of a number is always positive